# Explicit specialization, C++

Tags: c++, explicit-specialization

How to write explicit specialization for object

```
Car<T>
```

in virtual method clear()?

```
template <class U>
class List
{
   public:
        virtual void clear();

};


template <class T>
template <>
void List < Car <T> >::clear()   //Specialization U = Car <T>, compiler error
{
    ....
}
```

class car:

```
template <class T>
class Car
{
   T speed;
   ...
}
```

Compile error:

Error   16  error C3855: 'List': template parameter 'Car' is incompatible with the declaration h:...\List.hpp 75
Error   20  error C2264: 'List::clear' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called  h:...\List.hpp 75

But this construction is OK

```
template <>
void List < Car <double> >::clear()   //Specialization U = Car <T>, compiler error
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Does it work without the `template <>` line?

Comment: i think you actually need to define a explicit specialization List<Car<T> >, because that's what my compiler is complaining about : "invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct List<Car<T> >"

Comment: btw how does a Car look like?

Comment: the edited is a full specialization, not a partial as the previous one.

Answer (score 2):

I think the only way you could do this is:

```
template<class T>
class Car
{
};

template <class U>
class List
{
   public:
        virtual void clear();

};

template <class T>
class List<Car<T> >
{
    public:
        virtual void clear() { /* specialization */ }
};
```

or, non inline version:

```
template <class T>
class List<Car<T> >
{
    public:
        virtual void clear();
};

template <class T>
void List<Car<T> >::clear() {
   /* specialization */ 
}
```

since you are not really specializing `List<T>` but instead you are partially specializing it, given that a template type still appears. My deduction could be wrong, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[This faq item](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.7) should get you going.

Therefore it is something like this :

```
struct Car
{
};

template <>
void List < Car >::clear()   //Specialization U = Car <T>, compiler error
{
    ....
}
```